# Cookie maintain in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, httpcookie

I want to record the single cookie for maintain the quantity of a product and all product. how i can do this in c#.

are their any way to do this when i can check the existence of product in cookie. are someone have the code for it.

thanks

Comment: You didn't [search](http://www.google.gr/search?q=asp.net%20cookies) too hard before landing here, did you?

Comment: Why you no learn ASP.NET basics?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a cookie:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("name", "value");            
Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Getting the cookie value:

```
string cookie value = Response.Cookies["name"].Value;
```